# How to modify the scale attribute of a backlight in sysfs?

Tags: linux-kernel, sysfs, backlight

How can a user change the `scale` attribute of a backlight that is exposed in sysfs? On my machine it's located at `/sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl1/scale`. I tried using udev to add write permissions to the file and write to it, but that doesn't change it from `unknown`. Running `udevadm test /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl1` returns:

```
amdgpu_bl1: /etc/udev/rules.d/90-backlight-scale.rules:5 RUN '/bin/chmod a+w /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl1/scale'
amdgpu_bl1: /etc/udev/rules.d/91-backlight-scale.rules:5 RUN '/bin/echo non-linear > /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl1/scale'
amdgpu_bl1: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules:74 Skipping builtin 'path_id' in IMPORT key
amdgpu_bl1: Failed to update tags under /run/udev/tag/: Permission denied
```

After running the udev scripts, the file properties are

```
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 root root 4096 Mar 21 08:08 scale
```

Trying to write to it with `echo non-linear | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl1/scale` yields

```
tee: /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl1/scale: Input/output error
```

Is modifying `/sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl1/scale` at all possible?

Comment: I would expect not.  In general, if an entry in /sys is read-only, then it really is read-only.  In the case of `scale`, I suspect it should be telling you how to interpret `brightness`.  And even if it isn't "unknown" (like mine too),  I would expect it to be explaining a property of the hardware, and thus be immutable.

Comment: @DavidG. The things is that it's `unknown` for a lot of backlights when it should really be `linear`. At the same time I can't rule out a non-linear backlight being labeled as `unknown`. Someone suggested using a udev property for manual user control but I'm not yet sure how or what that is.

Comment: Well, in order for it to be known one must know: A) What the chipset does with the numbers B) What the backlight hardware does with that value C) how this maps to brightness.   I suspect A is linear.  I suspect B&C rarely are.  And in any case, you would need to identify both the chipset (done) and the video hardware, quite possibly beyond just the board level; and know how to combine these.  Component tolerances can also come into play.  I almost wonder that the concept of "known" is valid.